# Take over access rights from file system (SharePoint foundation 2013)

Tags: search, permissions, access, searchserviceapplication, access-rights

I am experiencing issues with my SharePoint Search Service Application.

1. User A has access rights to Folder A.
2. User B has access rights to Folder B.
3. The default content access account has read only permissions on Folder A and B.

Is there any way so that I can forbid User A to see the contents of Folder B when doing a search in SharePoint? If yes, How?

Thanks for your help,

Colin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is implemented by default if your users are on the same domain in both SharePoint and the FileShare. If it doesn't work, my guess is that your search service application is miss-configured.

Comment: Sorry for asking but I need to import my domain users to my SharePoint? How can I achieve this? Is there some way to synchronize it?

Comment: @Andr0mega No, but they need to be on the same AD.

Comment: So it's enough if the VM I created for SharePoint is in the domain? Guess I'll have to go over my search service application configuration once again. Thanks

Comment: @Andr0mega If your farm is connected to the same AD as the fileshare, yes